# SSH/Wget and port redirection

Tags: ssh, shell-script

Platform: Ubuntu 12.04

There is a internal web server that's behind firewall. I have ssh permissions to connect and redirect the port. I normally use ssh port redirection and point my browser to that port which works great.

I am trying to write a script so that I can connect to server, use wget to download the file. However when I start ssh, naturally my next statements in the shell script (wget statement) won't be executed until ssh command terminates. Putting ssh in background keeps it running and does not terminate.

What do I need to so that my shell script starts ssh session with port redirection, fires wget command locally and cleanly disconnects the session.

I can not connect back to my machine from other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just background it but specify a command like `sleep 60` to be executed on the ssh connection which will hold the connection open for 60 seconds, then close it once the command terminates.

Adjust 60 to be an appropriate length of time for your needs.